# jquery - twitter bootstrap - get value of check-box when cheked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a div with 3 checkboxes inside div. I want to get all of them to string with jQuery.
Im using this theme http://almsaeedstudio.com/preview/ 
the checkbox in forms --> general elements.
its changes the HTML of checkbook for the design,

div:

```
<div id="some_id">
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" value="3">
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
 $("#some_div input[type='checkbox']").on('ifChecked', function(event){
   arr='';
   $('div[aria-checked="true"]').find("input").each(function(){

      arr=arr+","+$(this).val();

});

 console.log(arr);
});
```

The script works, but I have 2 problems:

1. It doesn't get the value of check-box that just been checked. For example:

   - if I check 1, arr will be empty.
   - if I check 1 and 2,  arr will be ",1".
   - if I check 1 2 3, arr will be ",1,2".
2. How could I run this script when "unchecked"?

I tried:

```
$("#some_div input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(event){
```

It doesn't work on bootstarp checkboxes. This is only a issue in bootstrap, in regular html there is no problem to get values with "click".

thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote / click the check mark if you like the answer.

Comment: unless you are using some sort of plugin that changes the checkboxes there is no reason that using bootstrap should change anything. Create a demo that replicates problem

Answer (score 0):

First: Change `-` -> `=`

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Second: Change `name` inside the input field

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkgroup">
 <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="checkgroup">
 <input type="checkbox" value-"3" name="checkgroup">
```

Third: you can give it some `ID` for easy access:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="1" name="checkgroup">
```

Forth: Use jquery to do with it as you will:

```
 $("#checkbox1").click('click', function(){.. /*do something*/ .. });
```

Comment: Using IDs is not ideal in that case since you will have more than one checkbox and you can't have the same id twice. using classes would make more sense IMHO.

Comment: dosent work. in using checkbox this theme , http://almsaeedstudio.com/preview/ the checkbox in forms --> general elements.

Comment: It is working in the demo I provided. If it is not working for you then that's because you did not provide the full HTML markup of your page. Please update your question with the correct markup.

Answer (score 0):

when dealing with checkboxes, it might be better to use the `onChange`. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6j7y5xv7/)

try something like that:

```
<div id="some_id">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkgroup" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="checkgroup" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="checkgroup" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]', '#some_id').on('change', function () {
        var arr = '';
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked', '#some_id').each(function (i, ele) {
            if (arr.length > 0) {
                arr += ', ';
            }
            arr += $(ele).val();
        });

        console.log(arr);
    });
});
```

Comment: dosent work. in using checkbox this theme , almsaeedstudio.com/preview the checkbox in forms --> general elements.